# Cleveref and ametsoc

Tags: templates, cleveref

I really like cleveref.

And I've been using it when writing a manuscript with the [ametsoc style file](http://www2.ametsoc.org/ams/index.cfm/publications/authors/journal-and-bams-authors/author-resources/latex-author-info/)

But there is at least one problem: The appendix letters (which must be manually assigned and referenced in the text) get displaced.

Example:

```
\appendix[A]
\appendixtitle{Title name}
```

Should yield

> Appendix A
>
> Title name

But instead I get

> Appendix
>
> A
>
> Title name

I don't want to go over the entire text and replace my `\cref`s with the appropriate Fig. Eqn. etc... especially since I might want to reuse the text in another document, where sections might be chapters.

Any ideas?

---

Minimum working example

```
\documentclass[twocol]{ametsoc}
\journal{mwr}
\usepackage{cleveref} 
\begin{document}
\appendix[A]
\appendixtitle{Title}
  Blah blah
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing the issue?

Comment: Please advise where the file `ametsoc.cls` might be obtained from. It doesn't seem to be on the CTAN.

Comment: @Mico It's at the bottom of the ametsoc documentation page that I linked to

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `cleveref` package patches `\appendix` assuming it's a parameterless macro, which isn't true with `ametsoc`.

My strategy is thus to recover the correct definition of `\appendix` from the badly patched macro and doing the patch in a safer way.

```
\documentclass[twocol]{ametsoc}
\journal{mwr}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% split the badly patched \appendix command
% into the two parts: the first four tokens
% will restore the correct definition of \appendix
% and the rest is the patching text, stored
% into \appendtoappendix
\begingroup
\def\splitappendix#1#2#3#4#5\splitappendix{%
  \endgroup
  \def\appendix{#1#2#3{#4}}\toks0={#5}%
  \edef\cleverefappendixaddition{\the\toks0}%
}
\expandafter\splitappendix\appendix\splitappendix % \splitappendix will disappear
\xapptocmd\appendix{\cleverefappendixaddition}{}{}

\begin{document}
\appendix[A]           
\appendixtitle{Title}
  Blah blah
\end{document}
```

[image]

A possibly simpler strategy would be

```
\documentclass[twocol]{ametsoc}
\journal{mwr}

\let\goodappendix\appendix
\def\appendix{}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\let\cleverefappendixaddition\appendix
\let\appendix\goodappendix
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd\appendix{\cleverefappendixaddition}{}{}
```

that would obtain the same result, but requires codes intermixed with package loading.